# Apache ECharts not hiding axis pointer when programmatically hiding tooltip

Tags: javascript, echarts, apache-echarts

I programmatically trigger a tooltip to show and to hide in my chart. I do this by dispatching the `showTip` and `hideTip` actions on the chart.

`showTip` triggers a tooltip to show and shows the `axisPointer` as well. But when dispatching `hideTip` the tooltip is hidden, but the `axisPointer` remains visible until I move my mouse inside and out of the chart canvas.

Is it possible to hide the `axisPointer` as well by dispatching another action. Or is this just a bug in the code of ECharts?

https://codepen.io/isazulay/pen/wvYppNN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem occuring for some time, reported as a bug https://github.com/apache/echarts/issues/8892 but there seems it's not a high priority.

A hacky way I found that helps is to add a `showTip` with `dataIndex:-1` after the `hideTip`

```js
myChart.dispatchAction({
    type: 'hideTip'
});
myChart.dispatchAction({
    type: 'showTip',
    seriesIndex: 0,
    dataIndex: -1
});
```

[jsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/tv132pfd/)

Comment: Thanks! This workaround indeed works well. And since it's a bug this is probably the best way to tackle this problem